# Somehow I created a nondeterministic sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, text-processing

I created the following script:

```
#!bin/bash
cat > Top10 <<EOF
Linux Mint 17.2
Ubuntu 15.10
Debian GNU/Linux 8.2
Mageria 5
Fedora 23
openSUSE Leap 42.1
Arch Linux
CentOS 7.2-1511
PCLinuxOS 2014.12
Slackware Linux 14.1
FreeBSD
EOF
sed -ri "s/^[^0-9]*$//" Top10
sed -r "s/(.*)([[:space:]][[:digit:]]*.*)$/\2\1/" Top10 | sed -r "s/([[:space:]])([[:digit:]])/\2/" | sed -r "s/([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])/\1 \2/" > Top10
sed -r -i "s/(.*)/\L\1/" Top10
sed -r -i "y/[aeiou]/[AEIOU]/" Top10
sort Top10 -g -o Top10
cat Top10
```

When I run it a few times the following happens:

[image]

As you can see sometimes the Top10 file turns out empty and sometimes it turn out the way I needed it to be. I know that the command which replaces the extensions from the end to the front of a line is done poorly. I ran this script on a VMware virtual machine. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as off-topic because as it currently stands, it's not about Ubuntu within the scope as defined in [the help center](http://askubuntu.com/help). Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/719081/edit) your question to help explain what your **ubuntu-specific** problem or question is.

Comment: If you have a question about GNU Sed or shell scripting in general, you may be able to get help at [Unix.SE].

Comment: Another thing to notice: You shouldn't type `sh zadatak3.sh` to invoke the script. Typing the name of the shell on the command line when invoking a script is not the proper way to invoke a script. The correct place to indicate which shell to use is the `#!` line at the start of the script. You shouldn't be overriding that. You should have typed `./zadatak3.sh` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More specifically, pipes are not deterministic.

I.e. in a pipe such as this one:

```bsh
command1 file | command2 | command3 >file
```

[it's not guaranteed that `command1 file` will be executed before `command3 >file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37513/114435).

So the race condition between `command1 file` and `command3 >file` makes it so that sometimes the file is first read by `command1 file` and sometimes the file is first truncated by `command3 >file`, giving the expected output in the first case and a giving an empty output in the second case.

This can be fixed by using `sponge` (in the `moreutils` package) to write the output to the file, to make sure that the output gets written to the file only after the rest of the pipe has finished executing:

```bsh
command1 file | command2 | command3 | sponge file
```

Comment: I think one possible solution in addition to that would be  to turn sed commands into one single script , instead of piping it over and over.

Comment: @Serg Sure. Actually that would be the way to go (my answer only wanted to address why the problem showed up and how to fix simlar problems in general). In this specific case the way to go is [muru's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/719095/380067).

Comment: @StenSoft Since every command of the pipe is run in a subshell, each redirection is resolved by a different subshell, and since the order in which the subshells are to be run is not defined, there's a race condition between the first and the last command: running `for((i=0;i<20;i++)); do echo foo >file | echo bar >file; cat file; done` should be enough to be convinced of that.

Comment: @StenSoft I'm afraid it's often but not always: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14479882/. You problem is being convinced that the redirections are always resolved first. That is true for a single command, but not for commands in a pipe: in that case the resolution of the redirections for each single command is delegated to the subshell that executes the command.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -r "s/(.*)([[:space:]][[:digit:]]*.*)$/\2\1/" Top10 | sed -r "s/([[:space:]])([[:digit:]])/\2/" | sed -r "s/([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])/\1 \2/" > Top10
```

causes the file to be first overwritten with `> Top10` and only then processed by `sed` (the file is empty at that time)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to run 6 sed commands when you can do it in one:

```
sed -ri 's/^[^0-9]*$//; s/(.*)/\L\1/; y/[aeiou]/[AEIOU]/; s/(.*)([[:space:]])([[:digit:]]*.*)$/\3 \1/' Top10
```

Note, in particular, how the second pipe of sed commands could be combined into one expression if you just grouped your matches differently. Since you wanted to discard the leading whitespace anyway, and then add a space after the version, you could do that in the original match itself, by grouping the leading space and the version separately.